# Can't rsync files to NFS mount where file has special characters

Tags: linux, filesystems, nfs

I am trying to backup a few directories (Millions of files) and a handful (A thousand or so) have special characters.

For example, the source file is `'78192-File Name ? Name File.pdf'`
And rsync returns `rsync: recv_generator: failed to stat "/backup/homedirs/site/public_html/downloads/78192-File Name \#226 Name File.pdf": Input/output error (5)`

How can we copy these files without changing their filenames?

Comment: Perhaps the characters in filenames were created using different encoding and you need to mount the NFS share using the correct one using something like the iocharset mount option on Linux?

Comment: Seems like you're on the right path as we can create these files manually (touch 'File Name ? Name File.pdf') on the NFS share but copying the files from the filesystem to the share doesn't work....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you tar them?  Try to create a tar file of just one troubled file.  If it works, try using tar instead of rsync from one fs to another

e.g. If I want to copy /a to /b I would use this command

```
(cd /a; tar cpBfb - 20 . ) | (cd /b; tar xvBfb - 20 )
```

Comment: This is actually what we ended up doing.